# Why am I receiving errorr "Invalid character 'Then' at position 34. (IES 10080)

Tags: business-objects

I want the report to show a 0 in the Amount Approved column if the status is Declined or Cancelled. If any other status, show the amount approved.

=If ([Loan Status] = "DEC";"CAN") Then [Amount Approved] = 0 else ([Amount Approved])

Comment: What additional information do you need? The formula I am using is =If ([Loan Status] = "DEC";"CAN") Then [Amount Approved] = 0 else ([Amount Approved]) and I am receiving the error "Invalid character 'Then' at position 34. (IES 10080). I am not sure what the error means or how to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, errors in WebI don't always point to the actual cause of the problem.

The actual answer to your issue is that you are using "=" with a list (DEC,CAN).  With a list, you'll need to use the InList operator:

```
=If ([Loan Status] InList ("DEC";"CAN")) Then [Amount Approved] = 0 else ([Amount Approved])
```

That will work, but I'm not sure it'll give you what you expect.  This part: `[Amount Approved] = 0` will produce a value of `1` if `[Amount Approved]` is `0`, and `0` otherwise.

It's essentially:

```
    If Loan Status is either DEC or CAN
        Then If Amount Approved is 0
            Then 1
            Else 0
        Else Amount Approved
```

Comment: `[Amount Approved] = 0` is going to result in an error. You cannot check a variable for a value in the Then portion of the If statement.

Comment: @Isaac actually, it worked -- I tested it.

Comment: I am surprised that it works. I set up a similar scenario and it worked for me too. However, it seems misleading because you are not really changing the value of **Amount Approved**.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer is in alignment with your pseudo code if statement. However, your pseudo code if statement is **not** in alignment with your stated objective.

Here is what I think you want to use...

```
=If ([Loan Status] InList ("DEC";"CAN") Then 0 Else ([Amount Approved]))
```

A key point here is you cannot change the value of object that is coming from your data source. You can change a variable, but not like that.